# Show div when object is not visible anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, visibility, preloader

i have a small problem concerning a preloader. I've got a preloader from a third party that shows a couple of seconds ( depends on the ad ). I am able to show the preloader but the problem now is that i want to hide another div ( a game ) until the preloader disappears.

The preloader gets a visibility:hidden style in the object when its done. I've tried this without success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if($('#preloader').is(':visible')) {
    $("#game_container").hide();
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find a solution to your question or do you still have further questions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach an event listener to listen `on` show/hide, I recently encountered this type of problem myself. Here is the solution that I wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#preloader").on({
        "show": function(){
            $("#game_container").hide();
        },
        "hide": function(){
            // Do something
        }
    });
});

// Custom event handler for hide and show
(function ($) {
    $.each(['show', 'hide'], function (i, ev) {
        var el = $.fn[ev];
        $.fn[ev] = function () {
            this.trigger(ev);
            return el.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Once you have attached your own custom event handler to the `on` function, it will listen on hide and show events, which then you can use on your element as you need.

I hope this helps!

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. To clarify my question. The preloader timer is set by a third party. The preloader shows automaticly and disappears after some seconds ( the object is then set to visibility:hidden )

Comment: You have no control over the third party timer. So you mean to catch the object when it is visible and doing something with it. You can try doing a test which is to output to console "preloader visible" when the `#preloader` is visible. Let me know what happens then

Answer (score 1):

I've created a quick [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tLzxecza/) that does what you want:

HTML:

```
<div id="preloader">
    PreLoader
</div>

<div id="game_container">
    My Game
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#preloader { display:block; position:absolute; width:200px; height:200px; background:blue;; color:#fff; font-size:2em; }
#game_container { display:none; width:200px; height:200px; background:red; color:#fff; font-size:2em; }
```

JS:

```
var checkPreloaderInterval = setInterval(showGameContainerIfPreloaderHidden, 200);

function showGameContainerIfPreloaderHidden()
{
    if($('#preloader').is(':hidden')) {
        $("#game_container").fadeIn();
        clearInterval(checkPreloaderInterval);
    }   
}

setTimeout(function(){$('#preloader').fadeOut()}, 3000);
```

I've set an interval that checks if the `preloader` div is hidden. If it is, we show the `game_container`.

I have an artificial timeout that hides the `preloader` div after 3000 seconds. This isn't actually part of the solution, it just replicates the `preloader` being hidden.